# Implement Back button in In-app browser of PhoneGap

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am working on one cross platform mobile application in which I need to implement Back button in In-app browser of PhoneGap so that user can be navigated back to application page.

My Question is Is it possible to implement such button in PhoneGap? If yes, How I can achieve this functionality?

Comment: any progress on that?? I need it too